# Chart.js multiple include prevention

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am writing a number of Jenkins plugins, and I would like to use Chart.js in most of them. But every plugin is responsible for generation of a small piece of the page, which means that I am including Chart.js multiple times across the page:

```
<script src="${rootURL}/plugin/jenkins-report-rpms/Chart.js"></script>
<script src="${rootURL}/plugin/jenkins-report-jck/Chart.js"></script>
<script src="${rootURL}/plugin/jenkins-report-other/Chart.js"></script>
```

Is it possible to wrap Chart.js in some code to prevent double initialization of content? Maybe based on Chart variable already being initialized? I do not care about multiple script download, but I would like to avoid any possible side-effects from double initialization of the library.

Comment: why dont you import once in the head section and delete the other references?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap your Chartjs code (i.e. by changing your Chart.js file) to check for the existence of the global variable Chart (`window.Chart !== undefined`) before running the wrapped the code.

That said, what you should probably be doing is have a modular structure with each of your Jenkins modules (plugins) depend on the Chart.js module. See http://requirejs.org/ for one way to do this.

Comment: Ended up writing a separate plugin. Hoped to avoid that, but looks like it's the most reliable way to do that.